# Unicorn gets stuck in loop "Refreshing Gem list"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

While starting up, Unicorn will get stuck in a loop of

```
INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

No error message will show up.

Comment: Our solution to a similar question was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702154/unicorn-stuck-in-loop-refreshing-gem-list/42244608#42244608

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem and want to post the answer here, should someone else run into this problem.

Make sure your code is free of syntax errors!

For me fixing a syntax error (in one of my controllers) ended the loop and started Unicorn properly. I did not get any error messages in Unicorn, you might want to try to start using WebRat and see if an error pops up.